# Monitoring S3 bucket for documents availability

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I am new to AWS environment my requirement is to monitor the S3 bucket for a document using lambda function java in case if the document is available i have to trigger the endpoint URL where as Alfresco process get deployed.

how to implement the above mentioned functionality using lambda function java?

I am using intellij community edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you the idea.

here are the steps:

1. create the lambda to receive notifications from S3.
2. Lambda to send an SNS notification when a file upload event received from S3
3. subscribe an email address to the SNS topic to be notified
4. Setup the trigger on the S3 bucket.

Reference:
https://riptutorial.com/aws-lambda/example/21730/java-aws-lambda-s3-triggered

Hope this helps.